# Unknown provider: $firebaseProvider <- $firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

When trying to inject angularfire into my app I'm faced with an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseProvider <- $firebase
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNirebaseProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebase
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3705:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3710:45
at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880:23)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134:28
at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:913:26)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6579:13) angular.js:9778
```

Feel like I've tried everything regarding the order of including the angular firebase and angularfire libraries

at the end of my body

```
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->

<!--
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularFire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js'></script>
-->

<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

main.js
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('jeetAngFbApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $firebase) {

var ref = new Firebase('https://aol16tais32.firebaseio-demo.com/');
$scope.messages = $firebase(ref);


$scope.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
];
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include `firebase` in the module. I am not sure if `jeetAngFbApp`is the app name but something like this (probably in `app.js`):

```
angular.module('jeetAngFbApp', ['firebase'])

.run(function() {
})

.config(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an old version of Firebase - it doesn't support $firebase service.
try these imports instead:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.js"></script>
```

Also, see the version dependencies on AngularFire documentation web site https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#getting-started